# Summation of the function

Tags: functions

If $f(x)=e^{x+1}-1$. **Find the sum of all of the values of 'n'** that makes $g(x)$ differentiable over $\mathbb{R}$.

$g(x)=100|f(x)|-\sum_{k=1}^n|f(x^k)|$ such that $n \in N$.

I have no idea of how to procced but I can figure out from desmos.com that $f(x)\ge0$ for $x\ge-1$

But could not procced for $\sum_{k=1}^n|f(x^k)|$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sequence of hints, in the form of statements to be proven by the reader:

1. $f(x^k)$ is positive for $k$ even.
2. $f(x^k)$ crosses zero exactly once for $k$ odd, at $x=-1$.
3. Hence the derivative of $|f(x^k)|$ has a discontinuity only at $x=-1$ and only for $k$ odd.

For $g$ to be differentiable at $x=-1$, the discontinuity in the derivative of $100 |f(x)|$ must exactly cancel that of the sum.

**Lemma:** The above holds if and only if $$100 f'(-1) = \sum_{\text{k odd}}^n f(x^k)'|_{x=-1}$$
*Proof:* Exercise.

Now to answer the question, find a formula for $f(x^k)'|_{x=-1}$ (hint: it's proportional to $k$), evaluate the sum on the right, and find which values of $n$ make it equal to $100 f'(-1)$.  Note: There will be two such values of n!